# Does basic 2 PL always ensure conflict serializability?

Tags: databases, database-concurrency

While going through the DBMS book by Korth, it was mentioned :

" For a set of transactions, there may be conflict-serializable schedules that
cannot be obtained through the two-phase locking protocol.

Does this imply that basic 2 PL ensures serializability but does not always ensure conflict serializability ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,

If you use 2PL protocol you are guaranteed to have a conflict-serializable schedule but there are conflict serializable schedules which may not honour 2 PL protocol i.e. locking data items in the growing phase and releasing them in the shrinking phase.

Comment: Thnk u 4 da answer.